# Como armazenar os valores de uma tabela do phpMyAdmin em uma variável/matriz/array e usá-la no código do Arduino?

Tags: banco-de-dados, mysqli, phpmyadmin, arduino

Meu trabalho escolar consiste em um sistema básico de segurança usando frequências de cartão, de modo similar aos ônibus: passa cartão no leitor, se a frequência for X libera a catraca, se for não-X a catraca permanece fechada.

No meu caso, aproximo um cartão do leitor e o relé chaveia se eu definir sua UID (frequência do cartão) no código:

```
if (conteudo.substring(1) == "40 C8 12 D9") //UID
{
Serial.println("Acesso liberado.");
...
}

else
{
Serial.println("Acesso negado.");
...
}
```

O problema é que o projeto deve, em teoria, ser implementado em larga escala, ou seja, não posso armazenar manualmente muito mais de 100 UIDs (frequência do cartão), o Arduino não tem memória pra isso -- e daria muito trabalho em várias ocasiões.

O que eu fiz foi criar um site com preenchimento de formulário, um servidor local com Apache, um banco de dados com MariaDB e phpMyAdmin.

Meu desafio agora é pegar uma coluna desse banco de dados (que seriam as UID cadastradas) e jogar em uma variável para usar no códio do Arduino para ficar algo como:

```
if (conteudo.substring(1) == "$variavel_UID") //Todas as UIDs da tabela
{
Serial.println("Acesso liberado.");
...
}
  else
{
Serial.println("Acesso negado.");
...
}
```

Dessa forma, eu não precisaria nunca mexer no código do Arduino, só atualizar a tabela que já entrava automaticamente como um valor permissível.

Coisas que já tentei:

```
<?php
$query = "SELECT tabela from `usuarios`";
$result = mysql_query($query);
$fetch = mysql_fetch_row($result);
$
?>
```

.

```
<?php
$sql="SELECT tabela FROM `usuarios`";

$records=mysqli_query($dbconnect,$sql);
$json_array=array();

while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($records))
{
$json_array[]=$row;
}
echo json_encode($json_array);
?>
```

.

```
<?php
$colunas = array();
$selectColunas = mysqli_query(
$conexao,
"SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'banco_de_dados' AND TABLE_NAME = 'tabela';"
); 
while($coluna = mysqli_fetch_assoc($selectColunas)){
array_push($colunas, $coluna['COLUMN_NAME']) ;
}

print_r($colunas)
?>
```

E muitas outras... Tou há tempos tentando, mas não sou experiente nisso e nem pago matéria sobre.

A princípio, quero ao menos exibir os resultados da tabela em uma página HTML/PHP. Depois resolvo sobre a tradução pro código do Arduino, mas qualquer conselho sobre como proceder com o projeto.

**EDIT**

Consegui mostrar as UIDs em uma página php com o código:

```
<?php
    session_start();
  include_once("conexao.php")
?>
<html>
<head>
<title>JSON</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
  $dbselect = mysqli_select_db($connect, "Arduino");

    $sql="SELECT frequencia FROM usuarios";

    $records=mysqli_query($connect,$sql);
    $json_array=array();

    while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($records))
    {
        $json_array[]=$row;
    }

    echo json_encode($json_array);
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Se alguém souber aprimorar e jogar pro Arduino!

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import mysql.connector #Biblioteca para conexao com o banco de dados
import serial #Biblioteca para conexao com o monitor serial do arduino

#-------------------CONEXAO COM BANCO-------------------#
conexao_banco_de_dados = mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost", user="root", passwd="1202", db="Arduino") #Conexao propriamente dita

validar = conexao_banco_de_dados.cursor() #Criar o cursor, para executar o CRUD

validar.execute("SELECT frequencia FROM usuarios") #Variavel que armazena os dados da tabela 'frequencia' do banco de dados

dados_banco_de_dados = validar.fetchall() #Armazenar todos os dados selecionados

for dados_frequencia in dados_banco_de_dados:
    print ('\n{}'.format(dados_frequencia))
#-------------------------------------------------------#

#-------------------CONEXAO SERIAL----------------------#
#conexao_monitor_serial_arduino = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0', 9600, timeout=1.7) #Conexao propriamente dita

#uid = conexao_monitor_serial_arduino.readline() #Ler e armazenar a primeira linha do serial arduino na variavel 'uid'
uid = 'UID1' #Armazenado o valor serial, ou seja, da uid do cartao detectado pelo RFID
#-------------------------------------------------------#

#---------------------MAIN------------------------------#
validacao = 1 if (uid in dados_frequencia) else 0 #Validacao, se existe os dados ou nao na tabela do banco de dados

print ('\n{}\n'.format(validacao)) #Printar a resposta de validacao
#-------------------------------------------------------#

#----------------FIM CONEXAO SERIAL---------------------#
#conexao_monitor_serial_arduino.write(validacao) #Printar para o arduino a resposta de validacao

#conexao_monitor_serial_arduino.close() #Conexao com o monitor serial encerrada
```

O único problema é na saída (os dois prints):

> (u'UID0',)
>
> (u'UID1',)
>
> (u'UID2',)
>
> (u'UID3',)
>
> 0

Está de fato com os meus dados MySQL, mas não era para estar saindo 0 e sim 1. Talvez o "u'" esteja atrapalhando ou algo do tipo. Não sei como ajeitar, já tentei bastante. Alguma ideia?

Comment: É que quando você disse dados_banco_de_dados = validar.fetchmany(1)) você só falou isso, não que uid = UID0 você já tentou trocar o (validacao = 1 if (uid in dados_frequencia) else 0) ao invés de in, para not in para ver o que acontece? seria interessante também, printar o dados_frequencia pra saber como está formatado, se é uma array e etc, e também seria interessante ver se o in está realmente detectando se um elemento está em um "array" por exemplo: crie uma array aleatória e verifique se um dado que você sabe que está na array realmente está, com IN

Comment: Amigo, simplesmente altere o seu select para ele já buscar o UID que deseja validar, assim `validar.execute("SELECT frequencia FROM usuarios WHERE frequencia = 'UID1' ")`, assim ao executar o comando fetchall() você só precisa chegar se retornou alguma coisa, se retornou é porque existe então ta liberado, se o fetchall retornar vazio então não existe, não libera

Comment: Se você quer seguir por este caminho então altere essa linha do seu código `validacao = 1 if (uid in dados_frequencia) else 0` para ele verificar com um for, como no comentário não fica identado [este site](https://repl.it/@MuriloPortugal/Python-testes) para colocar o código que deve usar. Isso se dá pelo fato de como o fetchall retorna os dados.

Comment: Aparentemente resolvi o problema. Eu apaguei o **for for dados_frequencia in dados_banco_de_dados: print (dados_frequencia)** e subistitui o **dados_banco_de_dados = validar.fetchall()** por **dados_frequencia = [i[0] for i in list(validar)]**. As far as I can tell, tudo certo. Muito obrigado vocês dois por me guiarem no processo, isso realmente fez a diferença pra alguém que tá começando agora!

Answer (score -1):

Boa noite amigo.

> Meu desafio agora é pegar uma coluna desse banco de dados (que seriam as UID cadastradas) e jogar em uma variável para usar no códio do Arduino para ficar algo como:

Pelo que entendi você quer pegar as UID's que estão no banco e jogar para o arduino certo?
Mas o pricipal motivo de você guardar elas no banco não é porque a memória do arduino é pequena, então pensa comigo, se você guardar elas no banco e depois quer jogar ela para uma variável no arduino essa variável vai estourar a memoria dele.

Guardar no banco as UID's é a coisa certa, mas para validar a UID quando o usuário passar pelo sensor você pode pegar somente a UID dele (como você já mostrou ali no código conteudo.substring(1)) e enviar do arduino para o PC somente essa informação, esse envio da UID do arduino para o PC pode ser feito por serial,bluetooth ou rede, sendo que a serial você só precisa do cabo usb espetado no arduindo e a bluetooth e rede você vai precisar de shields para adicionar essas funções.

Bom, então depois de enviar o UID lido do arduino para o PC, você faz a verificação se esse UID existe cadastrado no banco de dados, se tiver você retorna um OK (ou 1 para ficar mais fácil) para o arduino e assim ele vai saber que pode chavear o relé, se não tiver cadastrado retorna um 0 e o arduindo não libera a catraca.
Essa validação e resposta no pc pode ser feita de várias maneiras, tudo vai depender de qual a forma vocês escolher fazer a comunicação, serial, bluetooth, wifi.

Ficou comprida a resposta mas tentei ser o mais detalhista possível para ficar claro.
Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Sim, verdade! Não tinha pensado nisso, mas me expressei pelo trecho do código. Esse é um problema, tem como eu validar uma UID no meio de 100 sem que todas estejam na variável? Pode me dar algum guia pra pesquisar como fazer isso?

Comment: Tem como validar sim, você envia UID do arduino para o PC, pode ser por serial que vai ser mais fácil. No PC você cria um programa que vai ficar "escutando" a porta serial, assim que o programa receber o UID ele verifica se existe no banco de dados, se existir ele responde 1 para o arduino ou se não existir responde 0. Se o arduino receber 1 ele sabe que o UID foi validado e esta cadastrado no banco, então ele libera a catraca, se ele receber 0 então não libera. Comece pesquisando sobre como comunicar arduino pela porta serial, tem muitos vídeos no youtube. qualquer coisa me avise!

Comment: Opa, voltei. Tirei um tempinho pra relaxar, mas já tou com a mão na massa. Olha o que eu consegui (vou responder a pergunta):